# Can I control frequency of mousemove event

Tags: javascript, mousemove, dom-events

I'd like to double the frequency of firing a `mousemove` event. Currently if I move my cursor over an element listening for `mousemove` event it will trigger `x` times, I'd like it to trigger `2x` times, is it possible?

Example code - make the console output 2 times more often `test` strings than currently

```js
const a = document.getElementById('test');
a.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
  console.log('test')
})
```

```css
#test {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: lightblue
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the attribute `dataset` to store a counter and after the `mouseevent` is called two times, remove the eventListener.

```js
const a = document.getElementById('test');
const listener = (e) => {  
  let times = e.target.dataset.mouseovertimes || 0;
  if (Number(times) > 1) {
    e.target.removeEventListener('mousemove', listener);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Event called!');  
  e.target.dataset.mouseovertimes = ++times;
  console.log('test');
}

a.addEventListener('mousemove', listener);
```

```css
#test {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: lightblue
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: This answer is completely unrelated to the question. I wonder why it is accepted...

Comment: @ArekDygas no, the answer it’s totally related.

Comment: care to explain how? What OP wants, is to effectively double the execution rate of the event handler, and the only real way to achieve that is to attach to mousemove event twice, each time a different handler (or simply an anonymous one). It is also possible to just use loop from 0 to 1, which would effectively execute the code twice, but this seems a bit awkward. In general, the whole question is a bit awkward, without any context. Your answer just states: execute handler once, then execute it again, see that it was the second time, and detach itself. I see no relation...

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, it is manipulated by browser.

If you want console to output 2 times more 'test' maybe try outputing twice in one function. That is the only way but I can see why that would not be ideal in many cases.